# Ruby regex: scan all

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string:

```
TFS[MAD,GRO,BCN],ALC[GRO,PMI,ZAZ,MAD,BCN],BCN[ALC,...]...
```

I want to convert it into a list:

```
list = (
[0] => "TFS"
    [0] => "MAD"
    [1] => "GRO"
    [2] => "BCN"
[1] => "ALC"
    [0] => "GRO"
    [1] => "PMI"
    [2] => "ZAZ"
    [3] => "MAD"
    [4] => "BCN"
[2] => "BCN"
    [1] => "ALC"
    [2] => ...
[3] => ...
)
```

How do I do this in Ruby?

I tried:

```
(([A-Z]{3})\[([A-Z]{3},+))
```

But it returns only the first element in [] and doesn't make a comma optional (at the end of "]").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the regex that the `,` is not required after each element, but instead in front of each argument except the first. This leads to the following regex:

```
str="TFS[MAD,GRO,BCN],ALC[GRO,PMI,ZAZ,MAD,BCN],BCN[ALC]"
str.scan(/[A-Z]{3}\[[A-Z]{3}(?:,[A-Z]{3})*\]/)
#=> ["TFS[MAD,GRO,BCN]", "ALC[GRO,PMI,ZAZ,MAD,BCN]", "BCN[ALC]"]
```

You can also use `scan`'s behavior with capturing groups, to split each match into the part before the brackets and the part inside the brackets:

```
str.scan(/([A-Z]{3})\[([A-Z]{3}(?:,[A-Z]{3})*)\]/)
#=> [["TFS", "MAD,GRO,BCN"], ["ALC", "GRO,PMI,ZAZ,MAD,BCN"], ["BCN", "ALC"]]
```

You can then use `map` to split each part inside the brackets into multiple tokens:

```
str.scan(/([A-Z]{3})\[([A-Z]{3}(?:,[A-Z]{3})*)\]/).map do |x,y|
  [x, y.split(",")]
end
#=> [["TFS", ["MAD", "GRO", "BCN"]],
#    ["ALC", ["GRO", "PMI", "ZAZ", "MAD", "BCN"]],
#    ["BCN", ["ALC"]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way using a hash to store your contents, and less regex.

```
string = "TFS[MAD,GRO,BCN],ALC[GRO,PMI,ZAZ,MAD,BCN],BCN[ALC]"
z=Hash.new([])
string.split(/][ \t]*,/).each do |x|
   o,p=x.split("[")
   z[o]=p.split(",")
end
z.each_pair{|x,y| print "#{x}:#{y}\n"}
```

output

```
$ ruby test.rb
TFS:["MAD", "GRO", "BCN"]
ALC:["GRO", "PMI", "ZAZ", "MAD", "BCN"]
BCN:["ALC]"]
```

Answer (score 0):

first split the groups

```
groups = s.scan(/[^,][^\[]*\[[^\[]*\]/) 
# => ["TFS[MAD,GRO,BCN]", "ALC[GRO,PMI,ZAZ,MAD,BCN]"]
```

Now you have the groups, the rest is pretty straightforward:

```
groups.map {|x| [x[0..2], x[4..-2].split(',')] }
# => [["TFS", ["MAD", "GRO", "BCN"]], ["ALC", ["GRO", "PMI", "ZAZ", "MAD", "BCN"]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you may want to get such array.

```
yourexamplestring.scan(/([A-Z]{3})\[([^\]]+)/).map{|a,b|[a,b.split(',')]}

[["TFS", ["MAD", "GRO", "BCN"]], ["ALC", ["GRO", "PMI", "ZAZ", "MAD", "BCN"]], ["BCN", ["ALC", "..."]]]
```